# Check value of array in Construct 2

Tags: html, arrays, algorithm, if-statement, construct-2

In my mind I want to do this:

```
If (my button is clicked)
    if(q_shuffled_arr_easy[0][5]) == 0)
        // do X
    else
        // do Y
```

For that reason I have structured my event sheet like this:

[image]

However, it doesn't work like I would like to, since `q_shuffled_arr_easy[0][5]` is *not* 0 when the button is clicked (its value is read on start of the layout and the debugger proves it's not 0), but it does X and not Y as intended. How to achieve my goal?

[image]

I've posted a more texty question in [Construct's 2 Forum](https://www.scirra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=147&t=186083).

---

Edit:

I also tried to compare with `str(0)` instead of `0`, but still the same behavior! Same with `int()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to fill the array with:

> Value: int(valueToInsert)

Then there is no need to specify a conversion when comparing.